# Why would Ethereum forks chose different Bip39 Derivation paths derivation path than ethereum?

Tags: private-key, forks, bip39

Just wondering why Ethereum forks like Ethereum Classic or others would chose a different derivation path than Ethereum? Having the same derivation path would guaranty greater support as it would be easier to implement the asset everywhere Ethereum is already supported. There must be a tradeoff I don't see, because as far as I know there is no conterside of having same derivation path as another network

Thanks very much for help!

Answer (score 0):

Coin type is part of derivation path for a reason. If you would have the same coin type, then transaction reply could be a security vulnerability

Comment: Thanks for reply! What do you refer to exactly as coin type?

Comment: I think I get what you mean, you refer tothe integer used as a kind of coin id in the derivation path. Ok thanks I see the trade off now